# Implementation of State Monad

Tags: haskell

I am working on a simple example to implement the state monad in Haskell. I have made a data type GlobState using record syntax. Functions incr1, incr2 and incr3 are there to increment the respective record elements. The code i have written is:

```
module StateExample where
import Control.Monad.State

data GlobState = GlobState { c1 :: Int, c2:: Int, c3:: Int} deriving (Show)

newGlobState:: GlobState
newGlobState = GlobState { c1=0,c2=0,c3=0 }

--incr1 :: State GlobState ()
incr1 = do
    gets c1
    modify (+1)

--incr2 :: State GlobState ()
incr2 = do
    gets c2
    modify(+1)

incr3 = do
    gets c3
    modify(+1)

main =  do
    let ((),a1) = flip runState newGlobState $ do
        x<- incr1
        y<- incr2 x
        z<- incr1 y
        return z
    print a1
```

This program is not giving the desired output. And i am not sure about the signature of increment functions or if gets is doing what i intend to do. Please help.

How can i make changes to the code so that instead of defining the different increment functions, i need to make only one increment function. i intend to do like:

```
incr :: String-> State GlobState ()
incr x = do
modify(\g -> g {x =x g + 1})
```

Comment: As a side note, we have another reason not to use tabs in Haskell source: it does not format well on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your types are right, at least.

```
incr1 :: State GlobState ()
incr1 = modify (\state -> state {c1 = 1 + c1 state})
```

Your `modify (+1)` would be fine if you were working in `State Int ()`, say, but we're not. You seem to think that `gets` focusses the following lines onto a particular field of the state --- but it doesn't.

`incr2` and `incr3` need to be changed similarly.

As to `main`:

1. You need to indent your code properly. You appear to want the `print a1` to be part of the outer do block, but not part of the inner do block. Without indentation, the compiler cannot figure that out.
2. You are (attempting to) manually thread the state, but the whole point about `State` is that its monadic/applicative plumbing does that for you.

```
main = do let ((), a1) = flip runState newGlobState $ do incr1
                                                         incr2
                                                         incr1
          print a1
```

Answer (score 3):

The types are a problem here - in this context:

```
modify :: (GlobState  -> GlobState) -> State GlobState  ()
```

This is a problem because:

```
modify (+1) :: (Int -> Int) -> State Int ()
```

So you need to write your function in terms of a GlobState like this:

```
incr1 = modify (\GlobState c1 c2 c3 -> GlobState (c1 + 1) c2 c3)
```

Alternative you can get and set the state separately:

```
incr1 = do
  (GlobState c1 c2 c3) <- get
  put (GlobState (c1 + 1) c2 c3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`modify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fclabels/1.1.0/doc/html/Data-Label-PureM.html#v%3amodify) from the [`fclabels`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-1.1.0) package and write it like

```
incr1 = modify c1 (+1)
incr2 = modify c2 (+1)
incr3 = modify c3 (+1)
```

I don't think it gets any more intentional than that.

Comment: I elaborated the use of `fclabels` in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078823/state-monad-exampleproblem) related question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that works, maybe you can build up from that.

```
module StateExample where
import Control.Monad.State

data GlobState = GlobState { c1 :: Int, c2:: Int, c3:: Int} deriving (Show)

newGlobState:: GlobState
newGlobState = GlobState { c1=0,c2=0,c3=0 }

incr1 :: State GlobState ()
incr1 = modify (\g -> g {c1 = c1 g +1})

incr2 :: State GlobState ()
incr2 = do
  modify (\g -> g {c2 = c2 g +1})


incr3 :: State GlobState ()
incr3 = do
  modify (\g -> g {c3 = c3 g +1})


main :: IO ()
main =  do
  let a1 = flip execState newGlobState $ do
      incr1
      incr2
      incr1
  print a1
```

Comment: You can also use `(\`execState\` newGlobState)` instead of pattern matching on the tuple from `flip runState`.

Comment: I tried to stay as close to the original code as possible.  But you are right, using `execState` is an improvement, so I changed that.  I like the section style, but kept what the original code used.