# State Monad ExampleProblem

Tags: haskell

I am working on this problem and had previously asked related question. [Implementation of State Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076881/implementation-of-state-monad) To further refine my code i tried to implement it using only one increment function.

```
module StateExample where
import Control.Monad.State

data GlobState = GlobState { c1 :: Int, c2:: Int, c3:: Int} deriving (Show)

newGlobState:: GlobState
newGlobState = GlobState { c1=0,c2=0,c3=0 }

incr :: String-> State GlobState ()
incr x = do
     modify(\g -> g {x =x g + 1})

main:: IO()
main =  do
    let a1= flip execState newGlobState $ do
        incr c1
        incr c2
        incr c1
    print a
```

But here i am getting an error

```
`x' is not a (visible) constructor field name
```

How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have hit a weakness in Haskell: records are not first class values!
Indeed, it would be very nice to write as you have done, but it is not possible.
However, you can use different libraries to achieve the desired effect.
This is how it looks if you use
[fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-1.1.0):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}
module StateExample where

import Control.Monad.State hiding (modify)
import Data.Label (mkLabels)
import Data.Label.Pure ((:->))
import Data.Label.PureM

data GlobState = GlobState { _c1 :: Int , _c2 :: Int , _c3 :: Int } deriving Show
$(mkLabels [''GlobState])

newGlobState:: GlobState
newGlobState = GlobState { _c1 = 0, _c2 = 0, _c3 = 0 }

incr :: (GlobState :-> Int) -> State GlobState ()
incr x = modify x (+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = flip execState newGlobState $ do
        incr c1
        incr c2
        incr c1
    print a
```

There are some magic parts here. We define the `GlobState` with the same
record names but prependend with an underscore. Then the function
`mkLabels` uses `TemplateHaskell` to define "lenses" for every field
in the record. These lenses will have the same name but without the underscore. The argument `(GlobState :-> Int)` to `incr` is such a
lens, and we can use the `modify` function from `Data.Label.PureM`
which updates records defined this way inside the state monad. We hide
`modify` from `Control.Monad.State`, to avoid collision.

You can look at the other
functions in the
[documentation for
PureM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fclabels/1.1.0/doc/html/Data-Label-PureM.html)
for other functions usable with state monads, as
`gets` and `puts`.

If you do not have `fclabels` installed, but you have the `cabal` executable from the `cabal-install` package (which you get if you install the Haskell Platform), you can install `fclabels` by simply running:

```
 cabal install fclabels
```

If this is the first time you run `cabal`, you first need to update the database:

```
 cabal update
```

Comment: module Data.Label.PureM is not there in library. How do i install it?

Comment: Updated my answer with some instructions how to install `fclabels`, which gives you `Data.Label.PureM` with cabal.

Comment: +1 perfect selling point for lenses (or "labels" or whatever you like to call them)